# How to sum the size of the Windows program without installing it?

Tags: windows, installation, extract

I know how to do this for **Inno Setup** based installers, but what about the rest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [`MsiEnumProducts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370101.aspx), [`MsiEnumFeatures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370098.aspx) and [`MsiGetFeatureCost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370115.aspx) should allow you to get a total of all features available in an MSI installer package. Depending on what you want to essentially achieve you may have to apply filters, if you don't want to account for optional features, for example.